# Excel VBA to powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am basically looking for a way to trim below code. It works just fine.

This code takes a range from each tab of an excel spreadsheet and pastes it into a powerpoint file, then assigns a title to each slide after pasting.

I feel the code is way too long and can be trimmed. I use excel 2016.

Everywhere the comment `'repeat` appears in the code is basically repeating the copy and paste from excel tab to powerpoint then assigning a title to that slide. I took some bits and pieces and trimmed them, but I feel there is room for more.

```
 Sub CommercialtoPowerPoint()

'declare variables

Dim otherWB As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet


Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim Sh As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim Bh As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim GSF As Workbook

Dim SlideTitle As String


'opening powerpoint and creating a new presentation

Set GSF = Workbooks("Support Function P&L Details FY23-Update File")

Set PP = New PowerPoint.Application
Set PPPres = PP.Presentations.Add
PP.Visible = True

'adding new slide to PP presentation and using for further use
Set PPslide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
PPslide.Select

'setting slide size from 16:9 to 4:3
PPslide.Application.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideSize = 1 'ppSlideSizeOnScreen = 1


'code to copy range from excel sheet
Sheets("Commercial-H1").Select

Sheets("Commercial-H1").Range("B3:L220").Copy

'pasting picture and adjusting positing
    With PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
        .Width = 666.72
        .Height = 390.24
    End With

PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True

Application.CutCopyMode = False


'Adding title to slide and align center
SlideTitle = "H1 P&L"

PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle

Set Sh = PPslide.Shapes.Title
Sh.Height = 20
Sh.TextEffect.FontBold = msoCTrue
Sh.TextEffect.FontName = Arial
PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered

Application.CutCopyMode = False


'repeat
Set PPslide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
PPslide.Select

Sheets("Commercial-LAM").Select

Sheets("Commercial-LAM").Range("B3:L220").Copy
    With PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
        .Width = 666.72
        .Height = 390.24
    End With

PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True

Application.CutCopyMode = False

SlideTitle = "LAM P&L"

PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle

Set Sh = PPslide.Shapes.Title
Sh.Height = 20
Sh.TextEffect.FontBold = msoCTrue
Sh.TextEffect.FontName = Arial
PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered

Application.CutCopyMode = False

'repeat
Set PPslide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
PPslide.Select

Sheets("Commercial-EMEA").Select

Sheets("Commercial-EMEA").Range("B3:L220").Copy
    With PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
        .Width = 666.72
        .Height = 390.24
    End With

PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True

Application.CutCopyMode = False

SlideTitle = "EMEA P&L"

PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle

Set Sh = PPslide.Shapes.Title
Sh.Height = 20
Sh.TextEffect.FontBold = msoCTrue
Sh.TextEffect.FontName = Arial
PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered

Application.CutCopyMode = False

'repeat
Set PPslide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
PPslide.Select

Sheets("Commercial-APAC").Select

Sheets("Commercial-APAC").Range("B3:L220").Copy
    With PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
        .Width = 666.72
        .Height = 390.24
    End With

PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True

Application.CutCopyMode = False

SlideTitle = "APAC P&L"

PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle

Set Sh = PPslide.Shapes.Title
Sh.Height = 20
Sh.TextEffect.FontBold = msoCTrue
Sh.TextEffect.FontName = Arial
PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered

Application.CutCopyMode = False

'repeat
Set PPslide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
PPslide.Select

Sheets("Commercial-HS Admin").Select

Sheets("Commercial-HS Admin").Range("B3:L220").Copy
    With PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
        .Width = 666.72
        .Height = 390.24
    End With

PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True

Application.CutCopyMode = False

SlideTitle = "HS Admin P&L"

PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle

Set Sh = PPslide.Shapes.Title
Sh.Height = 20
Sh.TextEffect.FontBold = msoCTrue
Sh.TextEffect.FontName = Arial
PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered

Application.CutCopyMode = False

'repeat
Set PPslide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
PPslide.Select

Sheets("Commercial-Corp").Select

Sheets("Commercial-Corp").Range("B3:L220").Copy
    With PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
        .Width = 666.72
        .Height = 390.24
    End With

PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True

Application.CutCopyMode = False

SlideTitle = "Corp P&L"

PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle

Set Sh = PPslide.Shapes.Title
Sh.Height = 20
Sh.TextEffect.FontBold = msoCTrue
Sh.TextEffect.FontName = Arial
PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered

Application.CutCopyMode = False



'repeat
Set PPslide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
PPslide.Select

Sheets("Commercial-all").Select
Sheets("Commercial-all").Range("B3:L220").Copy


    With PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
        .Width = 666.72
        .Height = 390.24
    End With
PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True

Application.CutCopyMode = False


SlideTitle = "Full P&L"
PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle

Set Sh = PPslide.Shapes.Title
Sh.Height = 20
Sh.TextEffect.FontBold = msoCTrue
Sh.TextEffect.FontName = Arial
PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered

Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Adding slide for Headcount and moving to last slide
Dim slideCount As Long
slideCount = PPPres.Slides.Count
Set PPslide = PPPres.Slides.Add(slideCount + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
PPslide.Select
PPslide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Headcount"

Set Sh = PPslide.Shapes.Title
Sh.Height = 20
Sh.TextEffect.FontBold = msoCTrue
Sh.TextEffect.FontName = Arial
PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered



'setting powerpoint title
Set PPslide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle)
PPslide.Select
PPslide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Monthly P&L Report"
PPslide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Commercial"



'back to excel sheet and select cell A1 in every sheet
GSF.Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False

For Each ws In GSF.Sheets
ws.Activate
ws.[a1].Select
Next ws
GSF.Worksheets(1).Activate


'powerpoint memory cleanup

PP.Activate
Set PPslide = Nothing
Set PPPres = Nothing
Set PP = Nothing
Set Sh = Nothing
Set Bh = Nothing
Set GSF = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Replace repeated operations with local helper methods

With the addition of helper methods, duplicated code can be greatly reduced.  Here,
copying a `Range` from a worksheet to update a PowerPoint Slide is repeated 7 times:

```
'code to copy range from excel sheet
Sheets("Commercial-H1").Select

Sheets("Commercial-H1").Range("B3:L220").Copy

'pasting picture and adjusting positing
    With PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
        .Width = 666.72
        .Height = 390.24
    End With
```

Create a helper subroutine:

```
Private Sub CopyToSlide(ByVal wkSheetName As String, ByVal PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide)

    Sheets(wkSheetName).Select
    
    Sheets(wkSheetName).Range("B3:L220").Copy
    
    With PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
        .Width = 666.72
        .Height = 390.24
    End With
End Sub
```

After making the simplest/easiest improvement, sometimes other opportunities to remove duplication become easier to see.  That is the case here.  Once `CopyToSlide` to used, it is easier to see a larger block of duplicated code.

With `CopyToSlide` the duplicated code lines now look like...

```
Set PPslide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
PPslide.Select

CopyToSlide <sheet name>, PPslide

PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True

Application.CutCopyMode = False

SlideTitle = <title>

PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle

Set Sh = PPslide.Shapes.Title
Sh.Height = 20
Sh.TextEffect.FontBold = msoCTrue
Sh.TextEffect.FontName = "Arial"
PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The only difference between the blocks of similar code is the worksheet name and  `SlideTitle`.  So, adding an additional subroutine that takes a PowerPoint.Presentation object, a worksheet name, and the slide's title can be used to eliminate the duplication:

```
Private Sub AddSlideForWorksheet(ByVal PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation, ByVal wkSheetName As String, ByVal SlideTitle As String)
    
    Dim PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Set PPslide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    
    PPslide.Application.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideSize = 1 'ppSlideSizeOnScreen = 1
    PPslide.Select
    
    CopyToSlide wkSheetName, PPslide
    
    PPPres.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle
    
    Dim Sh As PowerPoint.Shape
    Set Sh = PPslide.Shapes.Title
    Sh.Height = 20
    Sh.TextEffect.FontBold = msoCTrue
    Sh.TextEffect.FontName = "Arial"
    PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

With the addition of `AddSlideForWorksheet`, a lot of duplicated code has been removed.  That said, there is still a block of code that is duplicated *less*, but is still duplicated twice:

```
    Dim Sh As PowerPoint.Shape
    Set Sh = PPslide.Shapes.Title
    Sh.Height = 20
    Sh.TextEffect.FontBold = msoCTrue
    Sh.TextEffect.FontName = "Arial"
    PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered
```

This led to one last helper method `FormatTitle`:

```
Private Sub FormatTitle(ByVal PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide)
    With PPslide.Shapes.Title
        .Height = 20
        .TextEffect.FontBold = msoCTrue
        .TextEffect.FontName = "Arial"
        .TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered
    End With
End Sub
```

With these 3 helper methods, the length of `CommercialtoPowerPoint` is greatly reduced and the module's code now looks like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CommercialtoPowerPoint()

    'opening powerpoint and creating a new presentation
    
    Dim GSF As Workbook
    Set GSF = Workbooks("Support Function P&L Details FY23-Update File")
    
    Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
    Set PP = New PowerPoint.Application

    Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set PPPres = PP.Presentations.Add

    PP.Visible = True
    
    AddSlideForWorksheet PPPres, "Commercial-H1", "H1 P&L"
    AddSlideForWorksheet PPPres, "Commercial-LAM", "LAM P&L"
    AddSlideForWorksheet PPPres, "Commercial-EMEA", "EMEA P&L"
    AddSlideForWorksheet PPPres, "Commercial-APAC", "APAC P&L"
    AddSlideForWorksheet PPPres, "Commercial-HS Admin", "HS Admin P&L"
    AddSlideForWorksheet PPPres, "Commercial-Corp", "Corp P&L"
    AddSlideForWorksheet PPPres, "Commercial-all", "Full P&L"
    
    'Adding slide for Headcount and moving to last slide
    Dim slideCount As Long
    slideCount = PPPres.Slides.Count
    Dim PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Set PPslide = PPPres.Slides.Add(slideCount + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    PPslide.Select
    PPslide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Headcount"
    
    FormatTitle PPslide
    
    'setting powerpoint title
    Set PPslide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle)
    PPslide.Select
    PPslide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Monthly P&L Report"
    PPslide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Commercial"
    
    'back to excel sheet and select cell A1 in every sheet
    GSF.Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In GSF.Sheets
        ws.Activate
        ws.[a1].Select
    Next ws
    
    GSF.Worksheets(1).Activate
    
    'powerpoint memory cleanup
    PP.Activate

    'Removed statements setting local variables to 'Nothing'
    'When local variables go out of scope they are destroyed

End Sub

Private Sub AddSlideForWorksheet(ByVal PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation, ByVal wkSheetName As String, ByVal SlideTitle As String)
    
    Dim PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Set PPslide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    
    PPslide.Application.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideSize = 1 'ppSlideSizeOnScreen = 1
    PPslide.Select
    
    CopyToSlide wkSheetName, PPslide
    
    PPPres.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    PPslide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle
    
    FormatTitle PPslide
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Private Sub CopyToSlide(ByVal wkSheetName As String, ByVal PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide)

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wkSheetName).Select
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wkSheetName).Range("B3:L220").Copy
    
    'pasting picture and adjusting positing
    With PPslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
        .Width = 666.72
        .Height = 390.24
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub FormatTitle(ByVal PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide)
    With PPslide.Shapes.Title
        .Height = 20
        .TextEffect.FontBold = msoCTrue
        .TextEffect.FontName = "Arial"
        .TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered
    End With
End Sub
```

#### Declaring Local Variables

The VBA Language imposes a format/order for module variable and procedure declarations.  That is, the module-scope variables must be declared before the first procedure declaration.  So, it is common to find a list of variable declarations at the top of a VBA module.

The module-scope variable declaration rule often finds its way into the format of local-scope declarations.  However, local-scope variables (those declared within a procedure) are not required to be declared at the top of a procedure - they can be declared anywhere within the procedure. It is considered a Best-Practice to declared local variables as close as possible to their first use.  The reason behind the best practice is that it makes the code much easier to read/understand when the declaration and its first use.

#### Option Explicit

(Best Practice) Always declare `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules.  This allows the compiler to flag the use of variables that have not been explicitly declared.  This reveals hard to find bugs (i.e., due to typos).  *Make it automatic*: in the VBIDE, check the '*Tools -> Options...* -> (Editor tab) '*Require Variable Declaration*' option.

Comment: does not work :(...i was trying to use one vba code with button to do this. Not sure how to combine private sub with regular sub to do this.

Comment: @Sorab Learning to use small and focused functions to reduce repeated blocks of code is a very important skill to learn and apply in VBA or any programming language.  Otherwise, there are few options when "looking for a way to trim the code...".  I've added the 3 helper functions to the code example of the refactored `CommercialtoPowerPoint`.  Hopefully from the updated example you can see how to arrange and call a function from another function.